# mongodb stitch returns all fields

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongodb, mongodb-stitch

I'm trying to get just one field back for all my documents.

I'm new to mongoDB but I can't understand why this isn't working.

```
var docs = db.collection("articles").find({}, { _id: 0, title:1}).asArray();
```

I have this query which returns ALL fields, despite putting in the projection of wanting only the title field. The query runs without any errors. Maybe I'm missing something very obvious and need a second pair of eyes to spot it.

Any help is appreciated!

Note: I'm using the mongoDB Atlas' Stitch API.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your query so I'm guessing that your observation must be somewhat incorrect... Not sure how this would happen, though. Are you looking at cached output perhaps?

Comment: Are you doing this inside of a stitch function? Could you add an example of the data?

Comment: The line above is called after I connected to the database via. A promise call. I'm looking at the results via. Chrome debugger, stepped into every part of the code and nothing is broken. In the end it turned out I needed all fields anyway, but I'm still puzzled as to why the above didn't work

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that you're using [MongoDB Stitch Browser SDK](https://s3.amazonaws.com/stitch-sdks/js/docs/4/index.html) (currently version 4).

In this case, the `collection` is an instance of [RemoteMongoCollection](https://s3.amazonaws.com/stitch-sdks/js/docs/4/interfaces/remotemongocollection.html). Where [find()](https://s3.amazonaws.com/stitch-sdks/js/docs/4/interfaces/remotemongocollection.html#find) accepts options in [RemoteFindOptions](https://s3.amazonaws.com/stitch-sdks/js/docs/4/interfaces/remotefindoptions.html) format. You can define a `projection` to limits the fields of the matching documents by defining an object with `projection` key.

For example:

```
const client = stitch.Stitch.initializeDefaultAppClient('app-id');
const db = client.getServiceClient(stitch.RemoteMongoClient.factory, 'mongodb-atlas').db('databaseName');

 client.auth.loginWithCredential(new stitch.AnonymousCredential())
       .then(() => {
          db.collection('collectionName')
            .find({}, 
                  {"projection":{"_id":0, "title": 1}}
             )
            .asArray().then(docs => {
              // prints results 
              console.log(docs);
          });
        }).catch(err => {
          // Handle error here
          console.log("Error", err);
 });
```

Comment: Wan is correct. When calling `find` from a Stitch function, the projection is supplied as the second argument. When using the JavaScript SDK, the projection is supplied in the options object which is the second argument to `find`.